# How to include same random result in 2 diffrent php page?

Tags: php

```
main.php => include("". rand(1,3) .".php");
```

I need to include same result in main.php in a second page main_final.php.

How can i do for `main_final` to include same result that main.php?

thank you very much !

Comment: Save it in a text file or an SQL database.

Comment: i cant do it, because i have a lot of request each minute.

Comment: You have to save the value somehow, even if it's just in the session, else you'll likely get a different result each time you call `rand`.  Even if you wanted to use the same seed in both scripts (which is what you would need in order for `rand` to return the same value both times), you'd still need to save the seed.

Comment: whats the robust method to save a 1.php or 2.php or 3.php , each contain about 5 lines code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use variables to do that. Store you result in the proper predefined variable:
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php

And read the value from both files. For example in `main.php`:

```
$_SESSION["randomvalue"] = rand(1,3);
```

In the second file:

```
include($_SESSION["randomvalue"] .".php");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SESSION['page'] = rand(1,3) .".php";
include( $_SESSION['page'] );
```

so you can use the same variable in both pages. it can handle many users depending on your server. this is the best and the simplest way.